# Change output type of Data Lake Store Source in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Is it possible to change the output type of the columns when using Azure Data Lake Store Source?

At the moment it's `DT_WSTR(100)`, but in my source files contains bigger fields then 100 characters. So now the values get truncated and that's not the behavior I want to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to modify the column properties in the Advanced Editor. To do this you can follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the Azure Data Lake Store Source and choose `Show Advanced Editor`.
2. Click on the `Input and Output Properties` tab.
3. Expand `Azure Data Lake Store Source Output`, then both `External Columns` and `Output Columns`.
4. Under both `External Columns` and `Output Columns`, click on the column you want to modify and change the `Length` property.
5. `Ok` out of the Advanced Editor.

Comment: i was missing this part. i deleted my answer +1